# Eclipse Rulers background color

Tags: eclipse

1. How can I change eclipse Vertical Ruler background color?
2. what is name of the ruler/column that includes the folding circles?
3. How can I change the background color of the above ruler/clomun?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> what is name of the ruler/column that includes the folding circles?
> ```

It is known as the code fold margin, or simply fold margin.

> ```
> How can I change eclipse Vertical Ruler background color?
> How can I change the background color of the above ruler/clomun?
> ```

I am afraid Eclipse has a number of uncustomizable UI settings, and these two are among those. A feature request has already been raised to allow changing the code fold margin. [Background color for code folding](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=194313) Given that the request has been around for over 5 years, I am not very optimistic you would get a solution. You could comment on that issue to bump it up.

You could also make feature requests on their bugtracker page. https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/

Answer (score 1):

Usually I use my colors with the default settings that Eclipse provides, but I know many people that like alternative appearances for Eclipse (usually using a dark theme), so, I decided to give it a try...

For changing the default colors, there are some places that you have to look through in the window > preferences menu:

```
General > Editors > Text Editors (to set the background color / selection color, etc. for all editors)

General > Editors > Text Editors > Annotations (to set the colors for the occurrences highlight, tasks, etc.)

Pydev > Editor (to set the pydev editor-related colors)

General > Appearance > Colors an Fonts (to set what's not available in the other places)
```

Now, after you've properly set those colors, one thing you should really do is export the preferences you've just changed so that you can import them later.

To do that, go to File > Export > Preferences and export all the preferences to a file, then, open that file and remove all the non-color related preferences (except the file_export_version, which Eclipse requires when doing the import) -- note that you can keep other preferences you enter all the time too, and it might be easier doing it with a clean Eclipse install just with what you want to config (so that you don't have too many preferences in that preferences file).

Later, you can import those preferences in Eclipse through File > Import > Preferences.

The preferences for the dark theme I'm using gives the result below (note that you may have to restart Eclipse so that the left ruler looks correct):

Answer (score 0):

You can only configure what is shown in the vertical ruler using Preferences -> General -> Editors -> Text Editors -> Annotations. You cannot disable it.. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

It is not a thorough answer, but here is the SWT spy log I extracted while debugging:

```
AnnotationRulerColumn$5 {}@140230138540928
  Style: NO_FOCUS | LEFT_TO_RIGHT | DOUBLE_BUFFERED 
  Layout Data: null
  Bounds: Rectangle {44, 0, 9, 206}

Children:

Peers:
  *AnnotationRulerColumn$5 {}@140230138540928 Layout Data: null Bounds: Rectangle {44, 0, 9, 206}
  AnnotationRulerColumn$5 {}@140230141853568 Layout Data: null Bounds: Rectangle {0, 0, 12, 206}
  LineNumberRulerColumn$4 {}@140230140489248 Layout Data: null Bounds: Rectangle {12, 0, 32, 206}

Parent Tree:
[CUT]

                                                       Canvas {}@139916372127008
                                                         Style: LEFT_TO_RIGHT | DOUBLE_BUFFERED 
                                                         Bounds: Rectangle {0, 0, 954, 276}
                                                         Layout: org.eclipse.jface.text.source.SourceViewer$RulerLayout@4a767290
                                                         LayoutData: null
                                                        CompositeRuler$CompositeRulerCanvas {}@139916355542160
                                                             Style: LEFT_TO_RIGHT | DOUBLE_BUFFERED 
                                                             Bounds: Rectangle {0, 0, 29, 258}
                                                             Layout: org.eclipse.jface.text.source.CompositeRuler$RulerLayout@76b6b86f
                                                             LayoutData: null
```

``